# Connect SQL from remote host

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to connect mysql from my remote host , from a virtual machine.

I im using Squirrel SQL client or Heidi Sql client.

I can connect to them from local host, but not from my remote.

This is my Mysql configuration for hybris to connect to sql

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Hybris_testserver?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try by writing 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Or maybe,  the IP of the actual database server machine?

Comment: What error message are you getting when trying to connect? Are you using an IP address or host name? Have you checked that the host is indeed reachable from the remote host? What does the address look like?

Comment: Its working for 127.0.0.1 for connecting to my loaclhost @Sanchit.. but i want to connect the sql client for my remote host...

Comment: Im using IP something like eg: 10.22.98.222... @Pekka ... i tried to telnet the same ip, but it aint connecting

Comment: Well, then that's likely your problem. You'd have to check with the admin of the server whether it's accepting incoming mySQL connections at all. Many servers don't.

Comment: I also tried this GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.22.98.222'  and in mysql.cnf i commeneted out the line bind-address= 127.0.0.1

Comment: You sure there is no proxy which might be blocking your connection? Could you please share the error stack trace or any logs you got?

Comment: The only stack trace which i get is : Host 'some ip <not 10.22.98.222 >' is not allowed to connect to this Mysql Server...what is the possible cause?